# When talking about a year in the past, do you use by, in or before?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

There has been a few questions on this but this one example has never really been answered. If you were writing a report on the year before and you wanted to say that the a project was completed in that year, would you say:

1. In 2018, the Genesis project was successfully completed
2. By 2018, the Genesis project was successfully completed

The meaning I want to convey is that during 2018, the project was completed, not before.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> The meaning I want to convey is that during 2018, the project was completed, not before.

Then you should use

> In 2018, the Genesis project was successfully completed.

It was completed in that year and not before.

> By 2018, the Genesis project was successfully completed.

[could mean] it was completed by the end of 2017 and possibly even years before.

Comment: Just as I thought, thanks for the help!

Comment: Not necessarily. If you had been describing work on the project in previous years, it would be natural to say 'By 2018 it was completed'. However, as you are writing a report just on events of 2018, 'In' is probably better.

Comment: Sure. It would be natural to say that if you meant it was accomplished by the *beginning* of the year. You're right that in certain contexts it *could* mean "by the *end* of the year", though, so I'll emend the answer. All the same, "in" is much clearer and what Mr O'Donnell was trying to get across.